# Iterating over JSON list in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate over a JSON list to print out all of the results of the following:

```
"examples": [
  {
    "text": "carry all of the blame"
  },
  {
    "text": "she left all her money to him"
  },
  {
    "text": "we all have different needs"
  },
  {
    "text": "he slept all day"
  },
  {
    "text": "all the people I met"
  },
  {
    "text": "10% of all cars sold"
  }
],
```

I've tried to iterate over it by doing:

```
iterator = 0
json_example = str(json_data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['examples'][iterator]['text']).capitalize()
for i in json_example:
    print(i)
    iterator += 1
```

But this is only printing each letter of the first example, as oppose to the entire example, followed by other entire examples.

Can I iterate over these as I would like to, or do I need to create separate variables with each example?

Answer (score 1):

Only index the json data out to 'examples':

json_example = json_data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['examples']

then treat each element of 'examples' like a dictionary:

```
for dictionary in json_example:
    for key in dictionary:
        print(dictionary[key])
```

This will print out each value correlated with the key 'text', like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Following your code and example, it looks like what you need is :

```
for example in json_data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['examples']:
    print(example["text"])
```

In your code, by doing `json_data['results'][0]['lexicalEntries'][0]['entries'][0]['senses'][0]['examples'][iterator]['text']` you were only accessing the `iterator`th item, so, always the first one (iterator=0), and then iterating on the content of the "text" member.

Comment: Hmm but this gives me the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str, if I miss out the [0], [1], etc

Comment: @MegaS I tried to fit with your code, but if your json object is what you posted, a simple `for example in json_data['examples']:` would do the trick, otherwise, all the indirections are needed.